# iOS App Dev Best Practices for Turning features on and off

Tags: ios, authorization, toggle, feature-selection, usergroups

I have an App with a sign up, sign on process, in App Purchase to unlock features and several View Controllers exposed via NavigationControllers and hamburger menu's and buttons. I have a business requirement to implement a robust mechanism for turning features on and off for users (sort of like how its done on Web Portals)

I am looking for an elegant solution and do not want to reinvent the wheel.
I found some (Opensource) in this article here: https://featureflags.io/feature-toggles/ 
It describes LaunchDarkly ($$) and GroundControl etc. There's a server component as well where the list of allowed features will reside (that way it is dynamic)

Has anyone implemented such a mechanism in an iOS App or such a framework to turn features on and off for user groups? Appreciate any advice or tips.